# How secure is .htaccess?

Tags: internet, htaccess

I've got a personal website I wish to lock down to everyone else except me. I've been using an .htaccess file for a bit and quite like it (they don't even see a webpage, just the login box), but will this protect me from everything? And can search engines still scan me?

I'm thinking of adding password lists here and I want them to be locked down.

Comment: Can't help you if you don't mention what exactly you are doing with .htaccess, or post it.  You can put a lot of directives in there, and you haven't even told us which version of Apache (or other) you are using.  Can you fill in those details?  Please see the FAQ here:  http://superuser.com/faq  Also, you will likely get a better response over at http://www.serverfault.com.

Comment: support to move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

In terms of blocking search engines via user-agent string, that is fairly trivial. In terms of blocking **users** by their user-agent string, [**forget about it, it's a waste of time**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/).

If you are setting up a basic authentication login, be aware that these are susceptible to brute force attacks and passwords are sent in plain text. I would recommend using SSL if you are going to set this up for some added security. You may be interested in [**ModSecurity**](http://www.modsecurity.org/) as well if you are concerned about brute forcing.

I would recommend posting your .htaccess file as well before putting it in place so it can be evaluated for any problems.

Comment: Are you getting confused between robots.txt and .htaccess?

Comment: @Price, no: http://healyourchurchwebsite.com/2008/05/27/how-to-block-spambots-by-user-agent-using-htaccess/ . Crawlers can also send different user agents which can be annoying.

Comment: Right... but nohat says "they don't even see a webpage, just the login box". Suppose we do need to know more about the intended purpose and his current .htaccess.

Comment: Bah sorry but my main point was that "most popular search engines will respect the .htaccess file" - it isn't about the search engines 'respecting' it. That file is read by the web server and acted upon. If a search engine bot is masquerading as a standard firefox browser then well who's to say it isn't. I think you should have less emphasis that its the search engine's responsibility. .htaccess is a set of rules.

Comment: @Price poor choice of words, I agree. Modified.

Comment: Looks good, downvote removed!

Answer (score 1):

An .htaccess file is a set of instructions to your web server. If you tell it to require authentication before displaying pages, this will apply to *everyone*, search engines included (and only you have the password).

Make sure that your password file is not in a publicly-accessible directory. You can use this directive to completely block access to files starting with ".ht", although if your entire website is password-protected, this shouldn't be an issue.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht(.*)$">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that if your connection is not SSL-encrypted, this setup will not be entirely secure. Anyone between you and the web server can intercept your connection and sniff your password - for example, if you are using public wi-fi at a coffee shop. However, consider how much security you need, because SSL can be complicated and expensive to set up. For practical purposes, an .htaccess file should be sufficient to keep unwanted visitors away from your website.

P.S. Use [HTTP Digest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html) authentication instead of Basic - it's a little more secure.

Comment: SSL is "complicated and expensive"?  O.o

Comment: @Bacon I have to pay my hosting provider for a dedicated IP, and although StartSSL offers free certificates, it took me _forever_ (plus a few support calls) to set up. SSL might not be worthwhile; it depends on how much security you need.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to self-hosted systems with self-signed SSL, or hosted and purchasing an SSL cert for ~$10/yr (or getting one from our own root CA for work purposes).  I'm not sure why you required a static IP for that, however.  [SSL doesn't require that](http://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port).

Comment: @Bacon Basically, shared hosting providers (likely what nohat uses) use the Host: header to determine which website a client is requesting. However, this header isn't send until the connection is established, so a certificate would have to be presented _before_ the server knows which one to select. The SNI extension, which fixes this, isn't widely deployed. [http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=861105]. BTW, StartSSL [http://www.startssl.com/] offers free Class 1 certificates.

Comment: From apache 2.4 docs digest is less secure, read: "This module implements HTTP Digest Authentication (RFC2617), and provides an alternative to mod_auth_basic where the password is not transmitted as cleartext. However, this does not lead to a significant security advantage over basic authentication. On the other hand, the password storage on the server is much less secure with digest authentication than with basic authentication. Therefore, using basic auth and encrypting the whole connection using mod_ssl is a much better alternative."

Comment: Added because this post is still reachable through google